# How to Login LDAP with Jmeter?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, ldap

I am currently recording a web with **Login LDAP** that means I need to input username and password in popup authentication (screenshot attached).

[image]

After I am done recording, I play back the script, and it always failed.

And I followed tutorial from https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter but it still failed.

Here is my Test Plan:

[image]

Here is HTTP Authorization Manager setting:

[image]

Please help.

Thanks,
Rio

Answer (score 0):

1. If you really "followed the tutorial" you should know what is your authentication type challenge, the choice is in:

   - [Basic Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
   - [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
   - [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

     Your setup is wrong for any of the types as you should have either base url or domain or domain+realm+appropriate configuration in *jaas.conf* and *krb5.conf* files.
2. I don't think sending one request is sufficient for simulating log in process, real users do the following:

   - open login page (at least 1 request)
   - type credentials (you need to mimic the time required to type using [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers))
   - perform login (another at least 2 request)

     You may also need to perform **correlation** of dynamic parameters (if any), check out [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) to learn more about the concept / implementation
3. Your approach of AJAX requests simulation is wrong, as per the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) AJAX requests are **Asynchronous**, to wit real browsers execute them at the same time while in your setup they are sequential. So consider placing the AJAX calls under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)

Comment: Hi @dmitri, thank you for your reply, I already changed the config but still failed (screenshot attached above). Please help.